# Left join Fetch Not working on multiple conditions

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I am writing this query:

```
SELECT distinct g FROM Group g left join fetch g.groupPlaylists as gp on gp.playEndDay >= CURRENT_DATE and gp.status <>:status where g.zoneId= :zoneId and g.status <>:status
```

But it throwing an exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters [SELECT distinct g FROM com.instoreradio.model.Group g left join fetch g.groupPlaylists as gp on gp.playEndDay >= CURRENT_DATE and gp.status <>:status where g.zoneId= :zoneId and g.status <>:status]
```

Is there any solution to this problem?

It working without fetch but returning the wrong `GroupPlaylist`

Here is My Entity Mapping:
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "groups")
    @DynamicUpdate
   public class Group extends BaseModel {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4864520840627628591L;

private String storeIds;

private Long regionId;

private Long zoneId;

private Long groupManagerId;

private String groupName;

private String groupComment;

@JsonBackReference
//@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
private Companies companies;

@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="group",orphanRemoval=true)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private Set<GroupPlaylist> groupPlaylists=new HashSet<>();
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group_playlist")
@DynamicUpdate
public class GroupPlaylist extends JsonType {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -982336326147846219L;

@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
private Group group;

private Long groupCompanyId;

private String playlistTitle;

private Date playStartDay;

private Date playEndDay;

private Integer totalSongs;

private BooleanEnum isDefaultPlaylist;

@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "groupPlaylist", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
orphanRemoval = true)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private Set<TimeSlot> timeSlots = new HashSet<>();

@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "groupPlaylist", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
orphanRemoval = true)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private Set<StorePlaylist> storePlayLists = new HashSet<>();

@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "groupPlaylist", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
orphanRemoval = true)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private Set<GroupPlaylistSongs> groupPlaylistSongs = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: Please show your mapping of Group and Playlist

Comment: Please Look I have added the Entity too

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the on clause for further conditions than defined in the mapping.

You query must use the condition in the where clause like this:

```
SELECT distinct g 
FROM Group g 
left join fetch g.groupPlaylists as gp 
where gp.playEndDay >= CURRENT_DATE 
  and gp.status <>:status 
  and g.zoneId= :zoneId 
  and g.status <>:status
```

Comment: It will return the wrong result.
If some group doesn't have GroupPlaylist then that group will not return that group.

Comment: But you are doing a left join in your example. For your requirement you have to do a right outer join